# NestJS - Update retorna status 400 (Bad Request) em certas colunas

Tags: javascript

Estou desenvolvendo minha primeira api Rest em NestJS e me deparei com uma situação, a qual está me tirando dias de trabalho. Consigo criar um usuário normalmente, porém quando tento realizar uma atualização (update), ao atualizr certos campos, a atualização é realizada corretamente, porém alguns campos quando tento atualizar(roles, isActive), me retornam um erro com status 400 (Bad Request) e a mensagem: 'property [column] should not exist', entretanto as colunas existem no banco de dados e também estão corretamente listadas na entidade.

user.entity.ts

```js
import { Token } from 'src/modules/token/entities/token.entity';
import {
  Entity,
  Column,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  OneToMany,
  BeforeInsert,
  BeforeUpdate,
  CreateDateColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
  AfterLoad,
} from 'typeorm';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { Role } from 'src/modules/auth/roles/role.enum';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 60 })
  password: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isActive: boolean;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', array: true, default: [Role.User] })
  roles: Role[];

  @CreateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamp',
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
  })
  public createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamp',
    default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
    onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)',
  })
  public updatedAt: Date;

  @OneToMany(() => Token, (token) => token.user, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  tokens: Token[];

  private tempPassword: string;

  @AfterLoad()
  private loadTempPassword(): void {
    this.tempPassword = this.password;
  }

  @BeforeInsert()
  @BeforeUpdate()
  async setPassword(password: string) {
    if (this.tempPassword !== this.password) {
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);

      this.password = await bcrypt.hash(password || this.password, salt);
    }
  }
}
```

user.controller.ts -> função update

```js
@Patch(':id')
@Roles(Role.Admin, Role.User)
update(
  @Param(
    'id',
    new ParseIntPipe({ errorHttpStatusCode: HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE }),
  )
  id: number,
  @Body() body: UpdateUserDto,
) {
  return this.userService.update(id, body);
}
```

user.service.ts -> função update

```js
async update(id: number, user: UpdateUserDto): Promise<User> {
  const entity = await this.userRepository.preload({ id: id, ...user });

  if (!entity) {
    throw new NotFoundException(`User ID ${id} not found`);
  }

  return this.userRepository.save(entity);
}
```

retorno ao tentar atualizar as colunas 'roles' e 'isActive'

```js
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": [
    "property roles should not exist"
  ],
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

Comment: batendo o olho por cima, este erro parece partir de um validador (class-validator?), mas você não mencionou nenhum validador em seus trechos de código. É interessante você checar também o stack trace ou o erro que aparece no console, já que o erro de resposta da requisição não o mais detalhado possível

Comment: Desde já agradeço a resposta, também achei inicialmente que poderia ser erro com o validador, principalmente pq a rota do controller não chega nem a ser acionada, e no caso estou utilizando o validador class-validator, porém na entidade user não utilizo nenhuma validação além das próprias do typeorm. No console não me mostra nenhum erro, apenas a resposta de bad request no insomnia.

Comment: Eu diria pra você não usar as classes de entidades como DTOs para a API cara. Diria pra criar um DTO "intermediário" e mapear quando tiver que acessar os dados na camada de serviço.

Answer (score -1):

Problema resolvido, simplismente eu estava olhando para o lugar errado,
estava analisando simplismente a minha entidade "user.entity.ts", e assim como o colega @wkrueger mencionou, o problema estava na validação dos dados, a qual é realizada no DTO UpdateUserDto(update-user.dto.ts), e estava esquecendo de inserir as propriedades "roles" e "isActive".

Meu DTO antes:

```
import {
  IsString,
  Length,
  ValidateIf,
  IsOptional,
  MaxLength,
} from 'class-validator';
import { Match } from 'src/decorators/match.decorator';

export class UpdateUserDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  readonly firstName?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  readonly lastName?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @Length(6, 24)
  readonly password?: string;

  @ValidateIf((o) => o.password !== undefined)
  @Match('password')
  readonly confirmPassword?: string;
```

Meu DTO após inserir as propriedades que faltavam e disparavam o erro:

```
import {
  IsString,
  Length,
  ValidateIf,
  IsOptional,
  MaxLength,
} from 'class-validator';
import { Match } from 'src/decorators/match.decorator';
import { Role } from 'src/modules/auth/roles/role.enum';

export class UpdateUserDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  readonly firstName?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  readonly lastName?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @Length(6, 24)
  readonly password?: string;

  @ValidateIf((o) => o.password !== undefined)
  @Match('password')
  readonly confirmPassword?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  readonly isActive?: boolean;

  @IsOptional()
  @MaxLength(20, { each: true })
  readonly roles?: Role[];
}
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Caramba! Me ajudou hem! Eu nao sabia que tinha que por o @IsOptional em todos aqueles que não fosse obrigatorio.